# Microphone on webcam and sound with bluetooth is bad in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

My webcam and bluetooth headset works fine on Windows. In Ubuntu 23.04 my webcam's microphone is very bad, like I'm very far in a tank, and the sound in my headset is glitchy but not the microphone in my headset. So I end up using my bluetooth headset microphone and my sound card output with another headset for the sound.

Has anyone has had the same issue and solved it?